# my first mac os x program, build error. (xcode 6.2, object-c helloworld.m)

Tags: xcode

ld: warning: ObjC object file (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/CoreService.framework/CoreService) was compiled for iOS Simulator, but linking for MacOSX

ld: framework not found CoreImage for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem. At last I downgrade to xcode 6.1